# ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Directory part1 does not exist

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am having a problem in executing a script in Apache Pig. I have 3 files namely movies.csv, ratings.csv, tags.csv. First I want to load "movies.csv", then load "ratings.csv" and join both tables. But I am encountering an error in loading of the files. Code given by me is as follows,

```
register 'piggybank-0.15.0.jar'
DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
part1 = LOAD '/home/cloudera/ml-20m/movies' as (movieId: chararray, title: chararray, genre: chararray);
cat part1;
```

When I give "cat" command, I am getting an error,as

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Directory part1 does not exist.

java.io.IOException: Directory part1 does not exist.
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processCat(GruntParser.java:677)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

But I have the file at specified location. I don't know why pig is not able to recognize the input file. I have tried by placing the input file in hdfs and loading the file. But the error is same though. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part1 is not a file but a relation.When you use the LOAD command in Pig,you are instructing to load the contents of the file into a relation.You cannot use cat on a relation since the most common use of cat is to read the contents of files.
To display the content of part1 use

```
DUMP part1;
```

else if you insist on using cat, then specify the full path to the file

```
cat /home/cloudera/ml-20m/movies;
```